# Question that regards multiindex; if I have $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ how may I express $|x^\alpha| = |x|$ for some $\alpha$?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, schwartz-space

I mean, the notation $x^{\alpha} = x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}...x_n^{\alpha_n}$ for $\alpha = (\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n)$ and $|x|$ is the sum of all (?) So I don't see how that would be possible (if it is...) How should one so choose $\alpha$? A brief explanation would be really appreciated.

I understand however that for distributions, $$\partial ^\alpha f= \partial_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_n^{\alpha_n}f$$ and if all $\alpha_i = 0$ then no differentiation is made.

So what applies here?

Comment: So is this the question:  How to choose $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ so that $$\big|x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}\big| = |x_1|+|x_2|$$
for all $x_1,x_2$? If that is the question, then it is not possible.

Comment: @GEdgar Is there perhaps some inequality for $|x^{\alpha}|$ that I am missing? I.e. if it is possible to express $|x^{\alpha}| \leq |x|$ for some $\alpha$? Generally